# I want to increment the score when an answer is correct

Tags: javascript

I am making a quiz in which i have to solve the jumblewords. There are total 10 words as soon as a word is solved I want to increment the score the max score is 10. I have tried it using normal If else statement and then I have tried it using forloop but  my logic is not proper.

I have tried this logic but it didnt worked.

```
<script>
 $(".word").sortable({
   update: function(event, ui){
        /****** Upon every change in position of letter check if the updated word matches with the answer ******/
        var score = 0;

        var word = $(this).text().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "").replace(/ /g,'');
        for(var i=0; i<10;i++){
        if(word === 'JOY'){
            score++;
             $('.score').text(score);
            $(this).hide();
            $('.joy-win').show(500);
            $('.show-joy-btn').hide();
        }
        else if(word == 'BLISS')
        {   
            score++;
             $('.score').text(score);
            $(this).hide();
            $('.bliss-win').show(500);
            $('.show-bliss-btn').hide();
        }
        else if(word === 'REGARD')
        {   
            score++;
             $('.score').text(score);
            $(this).hide();
            $('.regard-win').show(500);
            $('.show-regard-btn').hide();
        }
        else if(word === 'THANKS')
        {   
            score++;
             $('.score').text(score);
            $(this).hide();
            $('.thanks-win').show(500);
            $('.show-thanks-btn').hide();
        }
        else if(word === 'GRATITUDE')
        {
            score++;
             $('.score').text(score);
            $(this).hide();
            $('.gratitude-win').show(500);
            $('.show-gratitude-btn').hide();
        }
        else if(word === 'PRAISE')
        {
            score++;
             $('.score').text(score);
            $(this).hide();
            $('.praise-win').show(500);
            $('.show-praise-btn').hide();
        }
        else if(word === 'GOD')
        {
            score++;
             $('.score').text(score);
            $(this).hide();
            $('.god-win').show(500);
            $('.show-god-btn').hide();
        }
        else if(word === 'ENOUGH')
        {
            score++;
             $('.score').text(score);
            $(this).hide();
            $('.enough-win').show(500);
            $('.show-enough-btn').hide();
        }
        else if(word === 'BLESSINGS')
        {
            score++;
             $('.score').text(score);
            $(this).hide();
            $('.blessings-win').show(500);
            $('.show-blessings-btn').hide();
        }
        else if(word === 'COMPARISON')
        {
            score++;
             $('.score').text(score);
            $(this).hide();
            $('.comparison-win').show(500);
            $('.show-comparison-btn').hide();
        }
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Are you missing some code? That's not syntactically correct.

Comment: What code? the HTML one?

Comment: The JS code - it starts with `update: function` which is incorrect. Although the HTML code is probably also needed, since you do a lot of HTML manipulation, too.

Comment: See I have updated the code

Comment: use `score` as a `closure` to the update function rather reinitiating every time update is called.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your counter all the time.
By executing the function your score gets all the time overwritten.

try to place it outside something like:

```
var score = 0;
function(){
do some stuff...
}
```